# How to set up SBT build to return zero exit code on test failure for Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, sbt, scalatest, specs2

When I am running my Specs2 tests in Jenkins via SBT, then the build is marked as a failure as soon as one test fails. Since Jenkins usually distinguishes between failure to build and test failures, I want to change this.

I know that the build failure in Jenkins is detected by the exit code of the call to SBT, which appears to return 1 as soon as at least one test fails.

What are the options I have assuming I want to avoid changing my `build.sbt` (or the project in general) just to fix this inconvenience?

Somehow I think it should be possible to put a standard sbt project into a standard Jenkins install and have it work as intended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `testResultLogger` with a custom test result logger that doesn't throw `TestsFailedException` that in turn sets the non-`0` exit code.

Just noticed that I missed that requirement *"to avoid changing `build.sbt`*. You can use any other `*.sbt` file, say `exitcodezero.sbt` or `~/.sbt/0.13/default.sbt` with the custom `testResultLogger`.

It turns out that since sbt **0.13.5** there's a way to have such behaviour - see [Added setting 'testResultLogger' which allows customisation of test reporting](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1225) where `testResultLogger` was born.

```
> help testResultLogger
Logs results after a test task completes.
```

As it may have been read in [the implementation of TestResultLogger.SilentWhenNoTests](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/actions/src/main/scala/sbt/TestResultLogger.scala#L95) that's the default value of `testResultLogger`:

```
results.overall match {
  case TestResult.Error | TestResult.Failed => throw new TestsFailedException
  case TestResult.Passed                    =>
}
```

It means that when there's an issue executing tests, `TestsFailedException` exception is thrown that's in turn caught to report it as follows:

```
[error] Failed: Total 3, Failed 1, Errors 0, Passed 2
[error] Failed tests:
[error]         HelloWorldSpec
[error] (test:test) sbt.TestsFailedException: Tests unsuccessful
```

My idea is to disable throwing the exception regardless of the outcome of executing tests. Add the following to `build.sbt` and have the exit code always `0`:

```
testResultLogger in (Test, test) := new TestResultLogger {
    import sbt.Tests._
    def run(log: Logger, results: Output, taskName: String): Unit = {
        println("Exit code always 0...as you wish")
        // uncomment to have the default behaviour back
        // TestResultLogger.SilentWhenNoTests.run(log, results, taskName)
    }
}
```

Uncomment `TestResultLogger.SilentWhenNoTests.run` to have the default behaviour back.

```
➜  failing-tests-dont-break-build  xsbt test; echo $?
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/java8/Contents/Home
SBT_OPTS= -Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jacek/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Set current project to failing-tests-dont-break-build (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/failing-tests-dont-break-build/)
[info] HelloWorldSpec
[info]
[info] The 'Hello world' string should
[info] x contain 11 characters
[error]    'Hello world' doesn't have size 12 but size 11 (HelloWorldSpec.scala:7)
[info]
[info] + start with 'Hello'
[info] + end with 'world'
[info]
[info] Total for specification HelloWorldSpec
[info] Finished in 15 ms
[info] 3 examples, 1 failure, 0 error
Exit code always 0...as you wish
[success] Total time: 1 s, completed Sep 19, 2014 9:58:09 PM
0
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. But the motivation of "not having it in `build.sbt`" should have been more like "not having to change the project".

Comment: Yes, that would be good enough. Didn't know you can also change the project instead of only the meta-project (for plugins) by placing things there. I'll try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the part of the build that runs the tests in a wrapper script that always returns 0. (If you run both the compile and the tests in one run you'd have to split that so you don't ignore build errors)

Comment: That's my last resort. But I didn't think about the splitting.

Answer (score 1):

Based Jacek Laskowski's solution you can do (at least in sbt >= 1.2.8):

```
    testResultLogger in (Test, test) := TestResultLogger {
      (log, results, taskName) =>
        try {
          (testResultLogger in (Test, test)).value.run(log, results, taskName)
        } catch {
          case _: TestsFailedException =>
            println("Ignore TestsFailedException to get exit code 0")
        }
    }
```

If you have multi-module project, you can implement it as a plugin:

```
object TestExitCodePlugin extends AutoPlugin {
  override def requires = JvmPlugin

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    testResultLogger in(Test, test) := TestResultLogger {
      (log, results, taskName) =>
        try {
          (testResultLogger in(Test, test)).value.run(log, results, taskName)
        } catch {
          case _: TestsFailedException =>
            println("Ignore TestsFailedException to get exit code 0")
        }
    }
  )
}
```