# java.lang.IllegalStateException if any of the JUnit Assertions failing

Tags: java, scala, junit, cucumber, sbt

I have written some Cucumber scenarios and added JUnit assertions in the steps.
If any of the assertions fail, the cucumber report comes with step failure, but cucumber plugin also throws following error.

```
[error] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cucumber did not succeed and returned error =1
[error] at com.waioeka.sbt.CucumberPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$6(CucumberPlugin.scala:116)
[error] at com.waioeka.sbt.CucumberPlugin$.$anonfun$projectSettings$6$adapted(CucumberPlugin.scala:91)
[error] at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error] at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:39)
[error] at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:66)
[error] at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:262)
[error] at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error] at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:271)
```

Following are the sbt changes..

Plugin Dependencies added:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.waioeka.sbt" % "cucumber-plugin" % "0.3.0")
```

Dependencies:

```
`lazy val qaDependencies = Seq(
"io.cucumber" % "cucumber-core" % "6.10.4" % "test",
"io.cucumber" %% "cucumber-scala" % "6.10.4" % "test",
"io.cucumber" % "cucumber-jvm" % "6.10.4" % "test",
"io.cucumber" % "cucumber-junit" % "6.10.4" % "test",
"io.cucumber" % "cucumber-java" % "6.10.4"% "test",
"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test",
"junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test")`
```

Project settings:

```
`lazy val testPro= project
  .settings(name := "testPro")
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= qaDependencies)
  .settings(crossPaths :=false)
  .enablePlugins(CucumberPlugin)
  .settings(CucumberPlugin.glues := List("com.waioeka.sbt"))
  .settings(CucumberPlugin.envProperties := Map("cucumber.execution.strict"->"true"))`
```

Any help on how to resolve this. This is causing the jenkins builds to go on error always if there is any assertion failure.

Comment: Wouldn't one want Jenkins to fail the build if there's an assertion failure?

Comment: Unrelated but you don't need to depend on `cucumber-core`. It's transitively provided by `cucumber-scala` and `cucumber-jvm`.

Comment: @LeviRamsey My point is in case of Junit/xUNIT tests run, if some tests failed, the Jenkins stage still goes to next stage, marking the Build as unstable instead of ERROR. Was expecting similar behavior here instead of breaking the jenkins build as ERROR in the cucumber test stage.

Comment: I was not aware of that behavior in Junit.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938212/how-to-set-up-sbt-build-to-return-zero-exit-code-on-test-failure-for-jenkins (especially the Apr 12 '19 answer for recent sbt versions) might help